# Write a Playfair encryption program

Tags: code-golf, cryptography

Write a program that takes two lines of input and uses the first as a key phrase to encrypt the second according to the Playfair encryption technique.

[Wikipedia describes Playfair encryption in some detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair_cipher), but to avoid any ambiguity, here's a brief summary:

**1. Generate a key table:**

Replace all occurrences of `J` in the key phrase with `I`, then strip all non-alphabet characters and repeated characters. Insert into a 5×5 encryption table, filling the remaining cells with the rest of the alphabet (except `J`; we don't like `J`).

Example:

```
                                        S T A C K
                                        O V E R F
Stack Overflow  -->  STACKOVERFLW  -->  L W B D G
                                        H I M N P
                                        Q U X Y Z
```

**2. Prepare the message to be encrypted**

Replace every `J` with an `I`, strip all non-alphabet characters and split into pairs, using an `X` to break any pairs that contain the same letter twice. If you end up with an odd number of letters, add `X` at the end. (Note: Numerals have to be spelt out in full — `ONE`, `TWO`, `THREE`, etc. — but you can assume this has already been done for you.)

Example:

```
In:
The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again.

Out:
TH EC AT CR EP TI NT OT HE CR YP TC RA PX PE DA ND CR EP TO UT AG AI NX
```

**3. Encryption**

Encrypt each pair of letters in turn. If they are in different rows and columns of the key table, replace each with the letter from the same row in the column where the other letter is found (e.g., `VM`⇒`EI`, `LZ`⇒`GQ`). If they are in the same row (or column), choose the two characters immediately to the right (or below), wrapping around if necessary (e.g., `OE`⇒`VR`, `ZG`⇒`KP`).

Example:

```
In:
TH EC AT CR EP TI NT OT HE CR YP TC RA PX PE DA ND CR EP TO UT AG AI NX

Out:
SI RA CA RD FM VU IC VS MO RD ZN AK EC MZ MF BC YN RD FM SV TV KB TM MY
```

The string produced by this process is the encrypted message, which your program should output.

## Rules:

- The input text and key may be obtained from `stdin`, command line arguments or other such sources. Hard-coded input is not allowed.
- Your program must accept both upper and lower case text for the pass phrase and message.
- The encrypted output may be upper or lower case.
- Your program should accept key phrases of at least 64 characters in length, and message texts of at least 16 KB.
- You are not required to handle non-ASCII input.
- You may ignore the possibility of the letter pair `XX` occurring during encryption.
- There is no need to add whitespace to the output of the program.
- Your answer should include an example of a message, key phrase and encrypted output produced by your program.
- **This is a code golf challenge, so the answer with the shortest code (in bytes) will win.**

---

> **NOTE:** Please remember that you only need to break consecutive letters if they appear **in the same pair**. So for example `MASSACHUSETTS` should be encrypted as `MA SX SA CH US ET TS` — the double `S` has to be split, but the double `T` doesn't.

Comment: "we don't like `J`" Do you harbour similar sentiments about APL?

Comment: Gobbledygook! (Although the lack of a J in its name is creditworthy, I suppose.)

Comment: Regarding the input requirement, are function arguments allowed? (not sure if this constitutes "hard-coding") If not, can we assume that the key contains no newlines (preferrably, the plaintext too)? If not, command line args might be more viable compared to stdin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### <del>J</del> I*, <s>536</s> <s>431</s> <s>417</s> <s>380</s> <s>263</s> <s>218</s> <s>203</s> <s>197</s> <s>186</s> 167

```
p=:4 :0
a=.u:65+9-.~i.26
,_2(5|,:~@|.@(=/)+$$,A.~5*1-0{=/)&.(5 5#:(~.n x,a)&i.)\(,'X'#~2|#)(({.,'X',}.)~1+2*1{&I._2{.\2=/\]) ::]^:_(n=:a(e.~#])'JI'charsub toupper)y
)
```

(with extensive suggestions from @algorithmshark)

example use:

```
   'Stack Overflow' p 'The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again.'
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY
```

splits input correctly:

```
   d=:(({.,'X',}.)~1+2*1{&I._2{.\2=/\]) ::]
   d^:_ 'MASSACHUSETTS'
MASXSACHUSETTS
```

---

*<sub><sup>replace every `J` with an `I`, right?</sup></sub>

Comment: We don't like J, but I is beautiful!

Comment: Wow, this is extraordinary.

Comment: While the first version looked a *bit* like witchcraft to me, this latest one is pure voodoo. Very impressive reduction.

Comment: Pop pop pop, watching keystrokes drop! If anyone wants an explanation of how this voodoo magic works, [here is a link](http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~ischtche/playfair.ijs); it's too long to fit in the answer without severe cramping.

Comment: I like J now :-)

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, <s>461</s> <s>411</s> <s>366</s> <s>359</s> <s>352</s> <s>346</s> 330 characters

```ruby
k,m=$<.map{|x|x.tr(?j,?i).upcase.tr('^A-Z','').chars}
t=[*((k&k)|[*?A..?Z]-[?J]).each_slice(5)]
m=(m*'').gsub(/(.)\1/,'\1X\1').chars
c=->n{[t.index{|r|k=r.index n},k]}
$><<(m.size%2<1?m:m+[?X]).each_slice(2).map{|p,q|a,b,d,e=*c[p],*c[q]
a==d ?[t[a][(b+1)%5],t[d][(e+1)%5]]:b==e ?[t[(a+1)%5][b],t[(d+1)%5][e]]:[t[a][e],t[d][b]]}*''
```

Thanks to @daniero for saving... err, a *lot* of bytes. \o/

Here's the ungolfed code:

```ruby
key = gets.chomp
msg = gets.chomp
transform = ->str{
    str.gsub! 'j', 'i'
    str.upcase!
    str.gsub! /[^A-Z]/, ''
    str.split('')
}

# 1. Generate a key table
key = transform[key]
chars = key.uniq + ([*?A..?Z] - key - ['J'])
tbl = Array.new(5) {
    Array.new(5) {
        chars.shift
    }
}

# 2. Prepare the message
msg = transform[msg]
msg = msg.join('').gsub(/(.)\1/){ "#{$1}X#{$1}" }.split('')
msg = (msg.length % 2 == 0 ? msg : msg + ['X']).each_slice(2).to_a

# 3. Encryption
coords = ->chr{
    i = -1
    [tbl.index{|row| i = row.index chr}, i]
}
msg.map! do |c1, c2|
    c1, c2 = coords[c1], coords[c2]
    if c1[0] == c2[0]
        # same row
        [tbl[c1[0]][(c1[1] + 1) % 5], tbl[c2[0]][(c2[1] + 1) % 5]]
    elsif c1[1] == c2[1]
        # same column
        [tbl[(c1[0] + 1) % 5][c1[1]], tbl[(c2[0] + 1) % 5][c2[1]]]
    else
        # neither
        [tbl[c1[0]][c2[1]], tbl[c2[0]][c1[1]]]
    end
end

# Output!
puts msg.join
```

Here's some sample outputs:

```ruby
llama@llama:...code/ruby/ppcg23276playfair$ printf 'Stack Overflow\nThe cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again.\n' | ./playfair.rb; printf 'This is a password!\nProgramming Puzzles and Code Golf is a Stack Exchange site.\n' | ./playfair.rb
SIRAVXRDFMVUUYVSBLRDZNYVECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBVBMY
WDDEDSXIXOQFBTUYVQFISQWGRPFBWMESATAHHGMBVEITQFFISHMI
```

Comment: Looks nice, but there's room for improvement: On the first line there's no need to "cast" `chars` into an array, assuming you're using Ruby 2. Also you can use `&` as a set operator instead of `tr`: `t=->s{s.gsub(?j,?i).upcase.chars&[*?A..?Z]}` (7 bytes saved). The two next lines can be joined with something like `k,m=[1,2].map{t[gets.chop]}` (note `chop` rather than `chomp`).

Comment: Using `&` also eliminates the need for `uniq` later. And the `chars` to array thing also applies to line 6.

Comment: @daniero Right, this was done a looong time ago, so there's probably lots more improvements I could make. Thanks for the tips; time to revisit this!

Comment: Yeah, I see that :) I stumbled upon the challenge and I immediately wanted to take a stab at it in Ruby, until I saw your answer.. The complexity of the code kind of scared me out of it, but I had to take a look at it :)

Comment: @daniero Unfortunately, `tr` to `&` on line 1 doesn't work because `m` can't be `uniq`ified. However, `k.uniq` can be shortened to `(k&k)` (1 byte off).

Comment: Aw, you're right. I didn't fully understand the usage of `m`.. Dang, that's some confusing code :D

Comment: @daniero Haha, yeah, even I'm having trouble understanding my own code. I shaved 50 bytes off, but I'm fairly certain way more is possible; I've got to go for now though.

Comment: @daniero 115 characters later... I'm still 5 chars above the C answer >_<. See any more optimizations?

Comment: Oh wow, that's a lot of golfing :) I think the second line is equivalent to `c=(k&k)|[*?A..?Z]-[?J]` ..? And the third line is just [`c.each_slice(5)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), isn't it? :)

Comment: @daniero I can't believe I missed `each_slice` there. I even used it later in the code! Thanks; Ruby is finally in its rightful place: shorter than C ;)

Answer (score 4):

## C: <s>495</s> <s>401</s> <s>355</s> 341 characters

<s>It's just a rough sketch as of now. I should be able to shave off at least a hundred characters.</s>

Goal accomplished: more than a hundred characters (154 as of now) have mysteriously vanished from the code.

```c
p[25],l[96],a=1,b,c;o(x,y){putchar(p[x%5^y%5?x/5*5+(x/5^y/5?y:x+1)%5:(x+5)%25]);}main(){for(;a&&((a=(b=getchar())>31)||(b=65))||b++<90;c=0)for(b&=-33;b/65-b/91&&p[c]^b-(b==74);p[c++]||(p[--c]=b-(b==74),l[b]=c));for(;b=getchar(),b=b>31?b&-33:(c=88),b=b/65-b/91?a?a^b?(c*=c==88,b):(c=b,88):(a=b,0):0,a&b&&(o(a=l[a],b=l[b]),o(b,a),a=c),c^88;);}
```

With some pleasant whitespace:

```c
p[25],l[96],a=1,b,c;
o(x,y){
    putchar(p[
        x%5^y%5
            ?x/5*5+(x/5^y/5?y:x+1)%5
            :(x+5)%25
    ]);
}
main(){
    for(;
        a&&(
            (a=(b=getchar())>31)||
            (b=65)
        )||b++<90;
        c=0
    )for(
        b&=-33;
        b/65-b/91&&
        p[c]^b-(b==74);
        p[c++]||(
            p[--c]=b-(b==74),
            l[b]=c
        )
    );
    for(;
        b=getchar(),
        b=b>31
            ?b&-33
            :(c=88),
        b=b/65-b/91
            ?a
                ?a^b
                    ?(c*=c==88,b)
                    :(c=b,88)
                :(a=b,0)
            :0,
        a&b&&(
            o(a=l[a],b=l[b]),
            o(b,a),
            a=c
        ),
        c^88;
    );
}
```

I wrote the first iteration of the program on the verge of falling asleep, so it had a lot of superfluous meaningless statements and such. Most of that is rectified, but there are quite a few areas where improvement is most definitely possible.

Comment: Well this is making my effort look very bad!! Looking forward to see how far you can go with this :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - 711

Demo:

```
[timwolla@/data/workspace/haskell/PCG]ghc pcg-23276.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pcg-23276.hs, pcg-23276.o )
Linking pcg-23276 ...
[timwolla@/data/workspace/haskell/PCG]./pcg-23276 "Stack Overflow" "The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again."
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY
```

Code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment
main=do a<-getArgs
    putStrLn$concat$map(x (a!!0))$map(\x->if (length x)==1 then x++"X"else x)$s 2$concat$map(\x->if (length x)==1then x else intersperse 'X' x)$group$p (a!!1)
p=map(\x->if x=='J' then 'I' else x).filter(isUpper).map toUpper
k x=y++(delete 'J'$['A'..'Z']\\y)where y=nub$p x
u l m=(div i 5,mod i 5)where i=fromJust$elemIndex l$k m
x y z
    |a/=c&&b/=d=(e!!(a*5+d)):(e!!(c*5+b)):[]
    |a==c=(e!!(a*5+(mod(b+1)5))):(e!!(c*5+(mod(d+1)5))):[]
    |True=(e!!((5*(mod(a+1)5))+b)):(e!!((5*(mod(c+1)5))+d)):[]
    where
        o=u(z!!0)y
        t=u(z!!1)y
        a=fst o
        b=snd o
        c=fst t
        d=snd t
        e=k y
s _ []=[]
s n l=(take n l):(s n(drop n l))
```

Large version:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe

encryptAll key text = map (encrypt key) (transformValue text)

clean x = map (\x -> if x == 'J' then 'I' else x) $ filter (isUpper) $ map (toUpper) x
transformKey x = y ++ (delete 'J' $ ['A'..'Z'] \\ y)
    where y = nub (clean x)

transformValue x = map (\x -> if (length x) == 1 then x ++ "X" else x) $ split 2 $ concat $ map (\x -> if (length x) == 1 then x else intersperse 'X' x) $ group $ clean x

search letter key = (div index 5, mod index 5)
    where index = fromJust $ elemIndex letter $ transformKey key

encrypt key chars
    | rowA /= rowB && colA /= colB = (key' !! (rowA * 5 + colB)) : (key' !! (rowB * 5 + colA)) : []
    | rowA == rowB = (key' !! (rowA * 5 + ((colA + 1) `mod` 5))) : (key' !! (rowB * 5 + ((colB + 1) `mod` 5))) : []
    | otherwise = (key' !! ((5 * ((rowA + 1) `mod` 5)) + colA)) : (key' !! ((5 * ((rowB + 1) `mod` 5)) + colB)) : []
    where
        rowA = fst $ search (head chars) key
        colA = snd $ search (head chars) key
        rowB = fst $ search (last chars) key
        colB = snd $ search (last chars) key
        key' = transformKey key

-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/12876438/782822
split :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
split _ [] = []
split n l
  | n > 0 = (take n l) : (split n (drop n l))
  | otherwise = error "Negative n"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Matlab - 458 chars

```
function p=pf(k,p)
k=[upper(k),65:90];k(k==74)=73;k(k<65|k>90)='';[~,i]=unique(k,'first');k=reshape(k(sort(i)),5,5);e=[k,k(:,1);k(1,:)];p=upper(p);p(p==74)=73;p(p<65|p>90)='';n=length(p);for i=1:2:n
if i<n&&p(i)==p(i+1)p=[p(1:i),88,p(i+1:end)];end
n=length(p);end
if mod(n,2)p=[p,88];n=n+1;end
for i=1:2:n [x,y]=find(k==p(i));[w,z]=find(k==p(i+1));p(i:i+1)=[k(w,y),k(x,z)];if x==w p(i:i+1)=[e(w,y+1),e(x,z+1)];end
if y==z p(i:i+1)=[e(x+1,z),e(w+1,y)];end
end
```

Some examples:

```
octave:180> pf('Stack Overflow', 'The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again.')
ans = SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY

octave:181> pf('This is a password!','Programming Puzzles and Code Golf is a Stack Exchange site.')
ans = WDDEDSXIXOQFBTUYVQFISQWGRPFBWMESATAHHGMBVEITQFFISHMI

octave:182> pf('Matlab needs lambdas', 'Who thought elseif is good syntax?')
ans = XGQMFQPKQDSACDKGRIFPQNILDMTW
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 111

Too late for competing, I just wanted to share. Here's 
[the encoder](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%40G%3Arb0%5Cj%5CiJ%7By%2BwGKywWhZ%3DZh%2a2xlR%7BRcK2+1IhZ%3DKXZK%5Cx%3BM%40J%2BG%3F%21eH5%3F%21hH%3Fq4%25G5_4+1eHVcK2A%2CxJhNxJeN%3DZ-V.DH5.DG5pgGZpgH_RZ&input=Stack+Overflow%0AThe+cat+crept+into+the+crypt%2C+crapped%2C+and+crept+out+again.&debug=0)
and 
[decoder](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%40G%3Arb0%5Cj%5CiJ%7By%2BwGKywWhZ%3DZh%2a2xlR%7BRcK2+1IhZ%3DKXZK%5Cx%3BM%40J%2BG%3F%21eH_5%3F%21hH%3F%21%25G5+4_1eHVcK2A%2CxJhNxJeN%3DZ-V.DH5.DG5pgGZpgH_RZ&input=Stack+Overflow%0Asiracardfmvuicvsmordznakecmzmfbcynrdfmsvtvkbtmmy&debug=0)

```
L@G:rb0\j\iJ{y+wGKywWhZ=Zh*2xlR{RcK2 1IhZ=KXZK\x;M@J+G?!eH5?!hH?q4%G5_4 1eHVcK2A,xJhNxJeN=Z-V.DH5.DG5pgGZpgH_RZ
```

**Explanation:**

```
L    b                              L defines common method y(b); 2 calls helps us saving two bytes
    r 0                             lowercase r(b,0)
   :   \j\i                         : replaces all occurrences of "j" with "i"
 @G                                 strips all non-alphabetic characters; G = pyth built-in alphabet

    w                               first input argument
   + G                              appends the alphabet (G)
  y                                 calls y(b)
 {                                  { makes set (removes duplicated characters)
J                                   assigns result to 'J' (KEY VARIABLE)

Kyw                                 assigns output from y(second input argument) to 'K' (TEXT VARIABLE)

WhZ                         ;       While (Z+1 != 0) <-> While (Z != -1) <-> While mismatched items found
             cK2                    list of K pairs.                    e.g. 'ABCCDDE' -> [AB, CC, DD, E]
         lR{R                       l length of { unique characters.    e.g. [2, 1, 1, 1]
        x       1                   1-length first index.               e.g. 1
     h*2                            *2+1 (Index in K)                   e.g. 3 'ABC CDDE'
   =Z                               Assigns to 'Z'
                  IhZ               if (Z != -1) <-> if (mismatched found)
                     =KXZK\x        X Inserts at Z index in K an 'x' and reassigns to 'K'  e.g. 'ABCXC...'

M                                   M defines function g(G, H) where G index H vector (INDEX CONVERSION)
     ?!eH                           if (same col)
         5                              then +5
         ?!hH                           else { if (same row)
             ?q4%G5                             then if (last col)
                   _4                               then -4
                      1                             else +1
                       eH                       else col
   +G                               index += increment
 @J                                 J[index]

VcK2                                V loops over cK2 list of K pairs
     ,xJhNxJeN                      x returns pair members index in J
    A                               A assigns G = xJhN, H = xJeN
                  .DH5              .D returns [row, col] = [i/5,i%5] of 5xn matrix from index of H
                      .DG5          idem. of G
                -V                  Subtracts vectors (RELATIVE POSITION)
              =Z                    Assigns to 'Z'
                          pgGZ          p prints g(G, Z) return value
                              pgH_RZ    p prints g(H, _RZ) return value, and _R changes signs of Z vector
```

**Sample Key/Message/Output:**

```
Stack Overflow
Gottfried Leibniz is famous for his slogan Calculemus, which means Let us calculate. He envisioned a formal language to reduce reasoning to calculation.
lfaukvvnrbbomwpmupkoexvqkovfimaqohflcmkcdsqwbxqtlintinbehcbovttksbtybsavmormwuthrhrbkevfxebqbspdxtbfsvfrwyarfrctrhmpwkrssbtybsvurh
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 516

Linefeeds added for improved <s>legibility</s> presentation. (Legibility went out the window, I'm afraid.)

```
#define Z(u,v) putchar(o[u]),putchar(o[v])
#define X while((Y=getchar())>31){Y&=223;if(Y==74)Y--;if(Y<65||Y>90
P,L,A,Y,f,a,i,r,c=512,o[25],d[2],*e=o;Q(){for(i=0;o[i]!=d[0];i++);i-=(f=i%5);
for(r=0;o[r]!=d[1];r++);r-=(a=r%5);if(f==a)Z(f+(i+5)%25,a+(r+5)%25);
else if(i==r)Z((f+1)%5+i,(a+1)%5+r);else Z(a+i,f+r);}main(){X||c&(A=1<<Y-65))continue;
c|=A;*e++=Y;}A=1;Y=65;for(P=0;P<25;P++){if(!(c&A))*e++=Y;
if(++Y==74)Y++,A+=A;A+=A;}L=0;X)continue;if(L&&Y==*d)d[1]=88,Q(),*d=Y;
else d[L]=Y,L=1-L;if(!L)Q();}if(L)d[1]=88,Q();}
```

**Example:**

```
$ ./pf
Playfair                                    
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
QMHNPEKSCBQVTPSVEPEFTQUGDOKGAYXFRTKV
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>709</s> <s>705</s> <s>685</s> 664

Accepts input from stdin.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as a
from itertools import product as d
import re
n=range
k=input()
p=input()
t=lambda x: x.upper().replace('J','I')
s=[]
for _ in t(k+a):
 if _ not in s and _ in a:
  s.append(_)
m=[s[i:i+5] for i in n(0,len(s),5)]
e={r[i]+r[j]:r[(i+1)%5]+r[(j+1)%5] for r in m for i,j in d(n(5),repeat=2) if i!=j}
e.update({c[i]+c[j]:c[(i+1)%5]+c[(j+1)%5] for c in zip(*m) for i,j in d(n(5),repeat=2) if i!=j})
e.update({m[i1][j1]+m[i2][j2]:m[i1][j2]+m[i2][j1] for i1,j1,i2,j2 in d(n(5),repeat=4) if i1!=i2 and j1!=j2})
l=re.findall(r'(.)(?:(?!\1)(.))?',''.join([_ for _ in t(p) if _ in a]))
print(''.join(e[a+(b if b else 'X')] for a,b in l))
```

Example:

```
mfukar@oxygen[/tmp]<>$ python playfair.py
Stack Overflow
The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again.
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY
```

Comment: Also works perfectly in Python 2.5 :-)

Answer (score 1):

## JS (node) - <strike>528</strike> 466

```
k=n(2)+'ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',p=n(3),t=o=''
for(i=0;i<k.length;i++)if(!~t.indexOf(k[i]))t+=k[i]
for(i=0;i<p.length;){a=f(c=p[i++]),b=f(!(d=p[i])||c==d?'X':(i++,d))
if(a.x==b.x)a.y=(a.y+1)%5,b.y=(b.y+1)%5
else if(a.y==b.y)a.x=(a.x+1)%5,b.x=(b.x+1)%5
else a.x=b.x+(b.x=a.x,0)
o+=t[a.x+a.y*5]+t[b.x+b.y*5]}console.log(o)
function f(c){x=t.indexOf(c);return{x:x%5,y:x/5|0}}
function n(a){return process.argv[a].toUpperCase().replace(/[^A-Z]/g,'').replace(/J/g,'I')}
```

Sample output:

```
$ node playfair "Stack Overflow" "The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again."
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY
$ node playfair "Lorem ipsum" "dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
CRORSDAHGAMQKPXDOFQMQAMSBSSPUPBPTDMOAHURNRCRLUAULRGNMLCPLSKDSBSBSQQAHMIGRERYMQCROREMAGDTSZIMUHAIAQRQALSGLAHSLZRQPIETAPDXRPNMSFRYMEBPZGHARKIEMIOGROIGREPUHSUPAQIMUHAPUOYRPGRLLRCRKPXDUYAINZ
```

Comment: Good point about the regex issue — I'll ad a note to the question

Comment: There's a problem with your second example — the pair of letters at characters 75 and 76 is encoded as `UU`. Looks like there was a repeated `E` that you should have split.

Comment: You're right, I shot myself in the foot. The problem is with only looking at pairs but ending up off by one after an insertion.

Answer (score 1):

### Python: 591 bytes

```
import sys
l=list
n=len
a=[sys.stdin.readline().upper().replace('J','I') for i in (1,2)]
b=l('ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
def z(x):
    a=0
    if x in b:
        b.remove(x)
        a=1
    return a
c=l(filter(z,a[0]))+b
d=[x for x in a[1] if x in c]
e=1
while e<n(d):
    if d[e-1]==d[e]:
        d.insert(e,'X')
    e+=2
if n(d)%2>0:
    d+='X'
def y(i):
    z=c.index(d[i])
    return z/5,z%5
x=lambda i,j:c[(i%5)*5+(j%5)]
def w(i):
    e,f=y(i)
    g,h=y(i+1)
    if e==g:
        z=x(e,f+1)+x(g,h+1)
    elif f==h:
        z=x(e+1,f)+x(g+1,h)
    else:
        z=x(e,h)+x(g,f)
    print z,
e=0
while e<n(d):
    w(e)
    e+=2
print
```

This uses `stdin` to get the key and the message in that order.  I hope it's not cheating to use a flat list to store the encryption matrix, because that made working with the matrix pretty simple.  Here are some example runs:

```
>python playfair.py
Stack Overflow
The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again.
SI RA CA RD FM VU IC VS MO RD ZN AK EC MZ MF BC YN RD FM SV TV KB TM MY

>python playfair.py
Stack Overflow
The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.
SI OX TU KS FR GR EQ UT NH OL ER VC MO BS QZ DE VL YN FL
```

Comment: I believe you can shorten `z` to `lambda x:0if b not in x else b.remove(x)or 1`. There's also quite a lot of whitespace you can get rid of. That would also let you move it directly into the `filter` call instead of defining it outside .

Answer (score 1):

### Java - 791

My first golf, so any criticism is welcome. Using Java because I shouldn't. It doesn't seem so bad; less than double the size of the current leader. I was expecting it to be bigger since it's, well, *Java* :)

```java
public class P{static String c(String s){return s.toUpperCase().replace('J','I').replaceAll("[^A-Z]","");}static int f(char[]a, char n){for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(a[i]==n)return i;return -1;}public static void main(String[]a){int i=0,k,l;char j=0;String g=c(a[0]);char[]e,b,h=c(a[1]).toCharArray();b=new char[25];for(;j<g.length();j++)if(j==g.indexOf(g.charAt(j)))b[i++]=g.charAt(j);for(j=65;i<25;j++)if(f(b,j)<0&&j!=74)b[i++]=j;e=new char[h.length*2];for(i=0,j=0;j<h.length;){if(i%2>0&&h[j]==h[j-1])e[i++]=88;e[i++]=h[j++];}if(i%2>0)e[i++]=88;for(j=0;j<i;j+=2){k=f(b,e[j]);l=f(b,e[j+1]);if(k/5==l/5){e[j]=b[(k/5*5)+((k+1)%5)];e[j+1]=b[(l/5*5)+((l+1)%5)];}else if(k%5==l%5){e[j]=b[(k+5)%25];e[j+1]=b[(l+5)%25];}else{e[j]=b[(k/5*5)+(l%5)];e[j+1]=b[(l/5*5)+(k%5)];}}System.out.println(e);}}
```

With auto-format:

```java
public class P {
    static String c(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase().replace('J', 'I').replaceAll("[^A-Z]", "");
    }

    static int f(char[] a, char n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if (a[i] == n)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int i = 0, k, l;
        char j = 0;
        String g = c(a[0]);
        char[] e, b, h = c(a[1]).toCharArray();
        b = new char[25];
        for (; j < g.length(); j++)
            if (j == g.indexOf(g.charAt(j)))
                b[i++] = g.charAt(j);
        for (j = 65; i < 25; j++)
            if (f(b, j) < 0 && j != 74)
                b[i++] = j;
        e = new char[h.length * 2];
        for (i = 0, j = 0; j < h.length;) {
            if (i % 2 > 0 && h[j] == h[j - 1])
                e[i++] = 88;
            e[i++] = h[j++];
        }
        if (i % 2 > 0)
            e[i++] = 88;
        for (j = 0; j < i; j += 2) {
            k = f(b, e[j]);
            l = f(b, e[j + 1]);
            if (k / 5 == l / 5) {
                e[j] = b[(k / 5 * 5) + ((k + 1) % 5)];
                e[j + 1] = b[(l / 5 * 5) + ((l + 1) % 5)];
            } else if (k % 5 == l % 5) {
                e[j] = b[(k + 5) % 25];
                e[j + 1] = b[(l + 5) % 25];
            } else {
                e[j] = b[(k / 5 * 5) + (l % 5)];
                e[j + 1] = b[(l / 5 * 5) + (k % 5)];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
>java P "Stack Overflow" "The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again."
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY

>java P "Write a PlayFair encryption program" "Write a program that takes two lines of input and uses the first as a key phrase to encrypt the second according to the Playfair encryption technique."
RITEWFCPGMWPGEBLYTWYQTXWINOLMWVNLECAXRNBURZWXWQILEWUWYWNQTFLDINWWEMICOTPYRIKWZRMGCBPGUOGPUWOKYGIQILYPFAPTIWMDPFLETGCEWODOWDZTZ
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 582

```
<? list($i,$k,$v)=array_map(function($v){return str_split(preg_replace('#[^A-Z]#','',strtr(strtoupper($v),'J','I')));},$argv);@$i=array_flip;$k=$i($k)+$i(range('A','Z'));unset($k['J']);$k=array_keys($k);$q=$i($k);for($i=1;$i<count($v);$i+=2){if ($v[$i-1]==$v[$i]){array_splice($v,$i,0,'X');}}if(count($v)%2)$v[]='X';for($i=1;$i<count($v);$i+=2){$c=(int)($q[$v[$i-1]]/5);$d=$q[$v[$i-1]]%5;$e=(int)($q[$v[$i]]/5);$f=$q[$v[$i]]%5;if($c==$e){$d=($d+1)%5;$f=($f+1)%5;}elseif($d==$f){$c=($c+1)%5;$e=($e+1)%5;}else{$t=$f;$f=$d;$d=$t;}$v[$i-1]=$k[$c*5+$d];$v[$i]=$k[$e*5+$f];}echo join($v);
```

[Ungolfed](https://github.com/einacio/codegolfing/blob/master/playfair.php)
[Decoder](https://github.com/einacio/codegolfing/blob/master/unplayfair.php)

outputs

```
$ php playfair.php "Stack Overflow" "The cat crept into the crypt, crapper, and crept out again."
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFECYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY
$ php playfair.php "This was codegolf?" "The full J answers is shorter than my preparation code :("
HIOKVGFHCMWTKZWSIYWIEPWAMWTCPNXQZKMOMEHSCPODEA
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 265

Very straightforward.

```
chomp(($k,$_)=map{uc=~y/A-Z//cdr=~y/J/I/r}<>."@{[A..Z]}",~~<>);1while$k=~s/((.).*)\2/$1/;while(/(.)((?=\1|$)|(.))/g){($a,$b,$c,$d)=map{$e=index$k,$_;5*int$e/5,$e%5}$1,$3||X;print substr$k,$_%25,1 for$a-$c?$b-$d?($a+$d,$c+$b):($a+5+$b,$c+5+$d):(++$b%5+$a,++$d%5+$c)}
```

Indented:

```perl
chomp(($k,$_)=map{uc=~y/A-Z//cdr=~y/J/I/r}<>."@{[A..Z]}",~~<>);
1while$k=~s/((.).*)\2/$1/;
while(/(.)((?=\1|$)|(.))/g){
    ($a,$b,$c,$d)=map{$e=index$k,$_;5*int$e/5,$e%5}$1,$3||X;
    print substr$k,$_%25,1 for
        $a-$c
            ?$b-$d
                ?($a+$d,$c+$b)
                :($a+5+$b,$c+5+$d)
            :(++$b%5+$a,++$d%5+$c)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## CoffeeScript - 610

Demo:

```
[timwolla@/data/workspace/js/PCG]coffee pcg-23276.coffee "Stack Overflow" "The cat crept into the crypt, crapped, and crept out again."
SIRACARDFMVUICVSMORDZNAKECMZMFBCYNRDFMSVTVKBTMMY
```

Code:

```
String::r=String::replace
_=(t,l)->
    for r in[0..4]
        for c in[0..4]
            return [r,c]if l is t[r][c]
K = {}
K[c]=c for c in (process.argv[2].toUpperCase().r(/J/g, 'I').r x=/([^A-Z])/g, '')
for i in[1..26]when i!=10
    c=String.fromCharCode 64+i
    K[c]=c
K=(c for c of K)
t=(K[s..s+4]for s in[0..24]by 5)
v=process.argv[3].toUpperCase().r(/J/g,'I').r(x,'').r(/(.)\1/g,'$1X$1').r /(..)/g, '$1 '
o=""
for p in v.trim().r(/\s([A-Z])$/, ' $1X').split /\s/
    [a,b]=p.split '';[d,f]=_ t,a;[e,g]=_ t,b
    o+=if d!=e&&f!=g
        t[d][g]+t[e][f]
    else if d==e
        t[d][++f%5]+t[e][++g%5]
    else
        t[++d%5][f]+t[++e%5][g]
console.log o
```

Ungolfed version:

```
search = (table, letter) ->
    for row in [0..4]
        for column in [0..4]
            return [ row, column ] if letter is table[row][column]

encrypt = (key, value) ->
    key = key.toUpperCase().replace(/J/g, 'I').replace /([^A-Z])/g, ''
    keyChars = {}
    keyChars[char] = char for char in key
    for i in [1..26] when i != 10
        char=String.fromCharCode 64 + i
        keyChars[char] = char
    keyChars = (char for char of keyChars)

    keyTable = (keyChars[start..start+4] for start in [0..24] by 5)

    value = value.toUpperCase().replace(/J/g, 'I').replace(/([^A-Z])/g, '').replace(/(.)\1/g, '$1X$1').replace /(..)/g, '$1 '
    pairs = value.trim().replace(/\s([A-Z])$/, ' $1X').split /\s/

    out = ""
    for pair in pairs
        [a,b] = pair.split ''
        [rowA, colA] = search keyTable, a
        [rowB, colB] = search keyTable, b
        if rowA!=rowB&&colA!=colB
            out += keyTable[rowA][colB]+keyTable[rowB][colA]
        else if rowA==rowB
            out += keyTable[rowA][++colA%5]+keyTable[rowB][++colB%5]
        else
            out += keyTable[++rowA%5][colA]+keyTable[++rowB%5][colB]
    out.replace /(..)/g, '$1 '

console.log encrypt process.argv[2], process.argv[3]
```